# Can somebody help me with a Pascal array

Tags: arrays, pascal

I need to convert the following code into simple C code.

```
Const LogoData : array [1..132*130*2] of byte =(...);
```

As far I know is a matrix of 132 by 130 and the first three lines are

```
$FF, $FF, $00, $10, $00, $10, $00, $08, $00, $08, $00, $08, $00, $08, $00, $08, 
$00, $08, $00, $10, $00, $10, $00, $10, $00, $10, $00, $10, $00, $18, $00, $20,
$21, $28, $62, $38, $C4, $48, $66, $61, $C8, $71, $49, $7A, $69, $82, $AA, $8A,
```

There’s a total of 2145 lines by 16 bytes and I don’t know how to interpret those bytes.
Is an image for a little 12bit LCD controller.

Could you help me to interpret this data?

Comment: Looks like a 8 bit color code.

Comment: Did you mean one byte per pixel? I was thinking that may can be 16 bit cause the array declaration have *2.

Answer (score 0):

Array size is `1..132*130*2` so 1 to 34320.  That match 2145 lines of 16 bytes.

For the rest impossible to say without additionnal information.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now, Is using a 16bit color palette. I don't understand why because the LCD controller have a 12bit color palette.

Comment: Probably easy of use with 4 unused bits.